# Learn a sum of angles from trigonometric functions of differences

Tags: trigonometry

I have a simple question which has proven surprisingly resistant to my attempts at algebra/application of intuition.

Suppose that I have two angular variables, $\phi_{1},\phi_{2}\in [0,2\pi)$, and that I am able to compute the functions $\sin(\phi_{1}-\phi_{2})$ and $\cos(\phi_{1}-\phi_{2})$. I'd like to pull from these functions of the sum of these angles, such as $\sin(\phi_{1}+\phi_{2})$. Is this possible in general? I haven't found a simple algebraic way to sort this out, but it would be nice to have, and it seems like it should be possible since I can compute both sine and cosine of the difference.

**Edit**: Also, if we can't compute things like $\sin(\phi_{1}+\phi_{2})$ given this data, it would be nice to see a proof if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that I know of, but if you know at least one of $\sin\phi_1 \sin\phi_2$, $\sin\phi_1 \cos\phi_2$, $\cos\phi_1 \sin\phi_2$, or $\cos\phi_1 \cos\phi_2$, you'll be able to get $\sin(\phi_1 + \phi_2)$ and $\cos(\phi_1 + \phi_2)$.

Comment: Right, unfortunately I don't think I have access to functions of a single angle. Thanks for the observation though.

Comment: Suppose that $~a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 = 80^\circ, 70^\circ, 50^\circ, 40^\circ,~$ respectively.  Then, $~\sin(a_1 - b_1) = \sin(30^\circ) = \sin(a_2 - b_2).~$  However, you have no way of determining (for example) if the angles $~(a,b)~$ correspond to $~(80^\circ,50^\circ), (70^\circ,40^\circ),~$ or some other two angles whose difference is $~30^\circ.$

Comment: @user2661923 Maybe post it as an answer? I think your point is enough, though you can probably generalize that $\sin(\phi_1 - \phi_2)$ and $\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2)$  cannot give a unique answer for $\sin(\phi_1 + \phi_2)$ and $\cos(\phi_1 + \phi_2)$.